# Android intent filter

Tags: android

I have written the below intent filter to open a text file using my app.  It seems to work but only sometimes.  For example, if I email a text file, if I choose open from mail, my app is not shown.  If I choose save first, then open, my app will be shown.  Similar experience with drop box, if I try to open from drop box, my app won't be listed as being able to open but if I export from drop box to sd and use a file manager to open it, my app is listed and works.

```
<intent-filter> 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
  </intent-filter>  
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
      <!--  <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" /> -->
  <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
   </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox and the Email app probably use content providers and don't match the `pathPattern`. Typically content providers don't include a file extension, but would use the mime type to indicate what type of file is being opened. If you are intending to open any `text/plain` file, and not necessarily only those which have the `.txt` extension, then you'd be better off leaving the `pathPattern` off altogether.

```
<intent-filter>
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I tried adding <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:mimeType=text/plain" /> but still no success

Comment: Edited my answer to include what the data element should look like. That should be all you should need to be considered for the view action.

Answer (score 0):

Probably beacuse the email app and dropbox uses a different scheme instead of file, http, or https. Try using the mime type attribute only.

**EDIT:** Acording to the dropbox forums:

> FYI, the easiest way to do this now is to open up your app from Dropbox by registering for VIEW with the correct mime-type. Then everything is handed off properly, and saving & watching file changes to re-upload is handled well.

You only have to specify the mime type, and nothing else. I haven't tried this though, but probably this works for the email app as well, as long as the mime types match.

Here is the link if you are interested:

https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=26035#post-162963

Comment: I tried adding 
    <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:mimeType=text/plain" /> 

but still no success